# Dependency issues when running beautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Anyone know how I can deal with errors arising from calling BeautifulSoup in Python3. It requires I install lxml. When I do pip install lxml however I am told that

```
 html-table-parser 0.1.0 has requirement beautifulsoup4==4.4.1, but you'll have 
 beautifulsoup4 4.6.3 which is incompatible.
```

Would it be possible to just change that requirement directly? If so where would I find it?

Comment: are you sure you don't mean lxml ?

Comment: can you provide more installation on how you installed beautifulsoup ? Python version, ...

Comment: I installed beautifulSoup through pip                                                                
edit: lxml

Comment: Removing the above error was achieved through removing python2 from the classpath (despite the fact that it was using python3) then upgrading BeautifulSoup4   pip install --upgrade BeautifulSoup4